# Why does adding a "/" after my url redirect to a html version on of my apache site?

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404

Apache Cent OS. I can edit anything thing on the server or website.

I enabled .htaccess to password protect a directory.

---

Main URL. This works

**abc.com**

---

This goes to the 404 page as it is supposed to.

**abc.comrandomn**

---

This goes to a html only version of **abc.com**. A watered down **abc.com**

**abc.com/randomn**

Adding the "/" does something. Can't figure out what.

---

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is what was going on.
I was using CentOS & Apache.

You have to set "AcceptPathInfo" to Off

More info on what it is at:
**http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html**
AcceptPathInfo Directive section

Edit the following file.
**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

Find the section 
**Directory /var/www/html**

Inside that section, add the line. You have to add it. It does not exist.
**AcceptPathInfo Off**

Restart apache afterwards.